# Why Primefaces commandButton does not redirect to the page?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean, trinidad

I use primefaces version 6.2  in combination with jsf and trinidaad.
In the project I have a table with each row containing a button to redirect this page to another page based on selected row.
jsf and trindad commandLink and commandButton does the job but primefaces commandLink and command button doesn't.

What I have already done:

1. Changed the type of button to `type="button"`
2. Added `immediate="true"`
3. I used `actionListener="#{coolingBean.view(row)}"` instead of `action="#{coolingBean.view}"`.

**Anyone know why and what should I change?**

```
<p:column id="viewButtonColumn" exportable="false" style="text-align: center" >
            <tr:commandLink textAndAccessKey="&amp;view " id="viewButton" action="#{coolingBean.view}" styleClass="commandLinkMediumSmallFont" onclick="PF('bui').show()">
                <tr:image source="/imgs/view.png" styleClass="commandLinkImageWithText"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.number}" target="#{coolingBean.criteria.number}"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.id}" target="#{searchBean.selectedId}"/>
            </tr:commandLink>
</p:column>

<p:column id="viewButtonColumn1" exportable="false" style="text-align: center" >
            <h:commandLink  textAndAccessKey="&amp;view " id="viewButton1" action="#{coolingBean.view}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" onclick="PF('bui').show()">
                <i class="fa fa-search" ></i>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.number}" target="#{coolingBean.criteria.number}"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.id}" target="#{searchBean.selectedId}"/>
            </h:commandLink>
</p:column>

<p:column id="viewButtonColumn2" exportable="false" style="text-align: center" >
            <p:commandLink value="View" id="commandLinkView" action="#{coolingBean.view}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" onclick="PF('bui').show()">
                <i class="fa fa-search" ></i>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.number}" target="#{coolingBean.criteria.number}"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.id}" target="#{searchBean.selectedId}"/>
            </p:commandLink>
</p:column>

<p:column id="viewButtonColumn3" exportable="false" style="text-align: center" >
            <p:commandButton id="viewButton2" value="View" action="#{coolingBean.view}" icon="fa fa-search" immediate="true" type="button" onclick="PF('bui').show()">
               <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.number}" target="#{coolingBean.criteria.number}"/>
               <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row.id}" target="#{searchBean.selectedId}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

**Inside managed Bean**

```
public String view(Row selectedRow) {
    if(criteria == null)
      criteria = new criteriaBean();

    criteria.setNummer(selectedRow.getNummber());
    searchBean.selectedId = selectedRow.getId();


 //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("view.jsp");
    return view();
  }

  public String view(){

    return"view';
  }
```

Comment: So it works if you don't use trinidad in the page or the project? Or if you do something like this without a `p:datatable` and `{coolingBean.view` is called? Just the redirect not working? Amd why the `type='button'`?

Comment: No it doesn't work at all. if i just use trinidad it works if i use primeface it doesn't work.
I want remove trinidad from my page and just using primefaces but primefaces button and command link doesn't work. I just used type='button' to see if it makes diffrence.

Comment: `type="button" is wrong, see the PF docs or stackoverflow. Better to create a real [mcve] without trinidad that fails. And remove the trinidad tag then since tags are for where the problem is and not what you use (and certainly not for what does work)

Comment: I have removed trinidad totally from my page but still primeface doesn't work.
Let me make myself clear. Originaly this project has been built up on trinidad. i have decided to change to primeface due to death of trinidad. this is the reason why i have to stick with trinidad in the project and slightly get rid of it.

Comment: That part was already clear. I'am just helping you narrow down the problem. Does an `h:commandButton` work? And there were more questions im my comment. Please do **AND** change the code accordingly into an [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This one](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=8750) actually helped me.

Basically adding one of the following did the trick for me:

- Adding `ajax="false"` into the commandButton
- Appending `?faces-redirect=true` to the url ( e.g. `return "view?faces-redirect=true';`)

Comment: Doesn't really *solve* the original question - rather, it circumvents the problem. In this particular case your solution works - but what happens when you actually need ajax? As suggested by @Kukeltje, your original question needs to be complemented with more code, because a number of things can cause the `commandButton` to not fire.